# Unlock files restored

Tags: files, unlock

I'm new to Ubuntu and just restored files and they are locked and was restored in home with files naming `recup_dir.1` and so on.

How can I unlock them and in which folder my pics are lying?

Comment: Welcome! How are they "locked"?

Comment: I installed ubuntu from windows and recover files by photorec that are now stored in home file

Comment: See https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf 11.11  PhotoRec: file name and date and 14.2  Renaming files using exiftool. Use sudo if you do not own the files.

Comment: Use sudo chmod 744 -R 'full_path_of_file_folder'

Comment: photorec runs as root. As Aravind suggests you need to change the permissions of the files in order to access them as a normal user

Comment: Sorry Aravind I am unable to unlock pl how to fill full path my files are in home with names such as recup_dir2 and so on give me an example. Thanks